# Binomial Coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I want to get ahead in my classes and learn Binomial Theorem ahead of time. What I know so far is that the formula below is the Binomial Coefficient:

$\binom n k = \frac {n!} {(n-k)!k!}$

and that you can sub in n and k for any number. However I am stuck on this particular problem:

*Simplify the following into one binomial coefficient:*

$ \frac {(n+2)!} {(n-2)!4!} + \frac {(n+2)!}{5!(n-3)!}$

Unfortunately the textbook gives no explanation on how to tackle this problem, so I dont even know where and how to begin. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ever heard of Pascal's identity?

Comment: @crash Unfortunately I haven't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a particularly bad problem to try to do algebraically because $k=5$, but $n$ is not determined. You said you have not heard of Pascal's identity. Here it is:
$$
\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}\qquad\text{where}\qquad 1\leq k\leq n+1.\tag{1}
$$
Looking at your problem algebraically, it appears to actually be easier to prove $(1)$ [even an algebraic proof of $(1)$ is pretty straightforward] and then use it instead of trying to fiddle around with a bunch of factorial manipulations.

Thus, we use $(1)$ to solve your problem:
$$
\frac{(n+2)!}{(n-2)!4!}+\frac{(n+2)!}{(n-3)!5!}=\binom{n+2}{4}+\binom{n+2}{5}=\binom{n+3}{5}=\frac{(n+3)!}{(n-2)!5!}.
$$

Comment: Could you show the steps on how you got the answer (n+3)!/(n-2)!5! ?

Comment: @user3170251 What is the binomial coefficient of the first fraction you listed?

Comment: I understand how you got (n+2, 4)+(n+2, 5), but what Im asking is how you got the answer (n+3, 5)

Comment: (the coeff. of the first fraction is (n+2, 4)

Comment: @user3170251 I got the answer by using the identity given in $(1)$ [Pascal's Identity]. Try it for yourself.